# Отключение Alt+Tab и Пуск

Tags: windows, windows-7, реестр

Подскажите, пожалуйста, где в реестре Windows 7 можно отключить Alt+Tab и Пуск?

Answer (score 3):

Чтобы отключить Alt+Tab, надо отредактировать значение ключа в реестре

```
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Desktop]
"CoolSwitch"="0"
```

Comment: Все равно всё сворачивается, что делать ?

Comment: а после установки значения перегружатся пробовали?